# Will kubuntu run happily "out of the tin" on a netbook?

Tags: kubuntu, ultrabook, kubuntu-netbook

I use Kubuntu on my desktop and am considering purchasing a new portable. I am thinking of an Acer S3-891 Ultrabook which runs on an Intel i5 3317U. I am aware that some processors for ultrabooks and netbooks have reduced instruction sets, and, whilst they are Windows8-friendly, will not necessarily support other operating systems. Has anyone experience of running Kubuntu on the Acer or indeed any laptop with a screen <14 ins?

Comment: the problem isn't so much bad cpu it's more about RAM. How much does it have? less then 2 GB could be a bit too slow. I hve an asus 1201n and everything ran way faster with 4 Gb of RAM instead of 2 GB...

Comment: If you try it, remember to use plasma-netbook instead of plasma-desktop, as it's tailored for netbooks.

Comment: As far as I understand *Ultrabooks* are fast, portable computers whilst *Netbooks* were low power machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run KDE interface on two netbooks. The key item is the vertical resolution. If the vertical resolution is greater or equal to 768 it seems to be the magic number. When I had a 600px resolution I spent a lot of time moving windows about to click buttons. Even the install was difficult.

The fans tended to be noisy and had to have custom drivers installed. Although that is probably less of an issue with the current netbooks